# how to send push Notifications to other device in android?

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-notification-bar

Using this code, i am able to send a notification to my own device.

```
           Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ContactDonor.class);
            PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);
            //display text
            String body = "Please Click on this to accept!";
            String title = bloodgroup+" Required";
            Notification n = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, body , System.currentTimeMillis());
            n.setLatestEventInfo(getApplicationContext(), title, body, pi);
            n.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_ALL;
            nm.notify(uniqueID, n);
            finish();
```

But now i have a screen where a person's details are displayed like:
 Name: ...
 email: ...
, and there is a message box and a Request Button , on the click of that button, he should receive a notification with that particular message. How can this particular thing be done?

Comment: Can you elaborate your requirement? What you have done is just implemented simple notifications and not PUSH notifications. What exactly you want on other device?

Comment: I want that when this request button is clicked, that person should receive a message whatever the user passed, in form of a  Push-Notification. I do not know the mechanism of a push_notification. Help me out with that

Comment: In your case, its not the PUSH notifications that will be useful. Have you implemented server-client comm? If yes then, pass a message from server to client and show it on your device. If not then show a custom message from same device which is not a big deal. I think, what I understood is not your actual problem. Is it like you want to send a message from your device to another device when user presses request button which is on other device?

Comment: Yes exactly i want to send a message from my device to another! Is it not done with the help of PUSH-NOTIFICATIONS ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It cannot be implemented by using `PUSH notifications`. `PUSH notification` is useful when there is `server-client` comm is implemented where `server` notifies the `client` about the event that has occurred on `server` side.

What you are trying to implement indirectly is server-client architecture, where your device will act as server. If you mould your current architecture to server-client you will be able to send notification to other device. In this case also, you don't need PUSH notifications, it will be a simple server-client communication.

For more info on PUSH please see: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidCloudToDeviceMessaging/article.html#c2dm_sendmessage

You can also send SMS, but that will not solve your problem. According to me, there is no other solution that you can apply to send notification.